# SQL variable containing a list

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

Let's say I have two tables : `cakes` and `dudes`.

A row of `cakes` in json looks like this :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot cake",
    "slices" : 8,
    "eaten_by" : ?
}
```

A row of `dudes` in json looks like this :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Ahsoka"
}
```

In `eaten_by` variable, I want to keep record of every person that ate a slice of cake.
For example, the json result would be :

```
{
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "Carrot Cake",
    "slices" : 8,
    "eaten_by" : {
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "name" : "Ahsoka"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "CT-7567 Rex"
        },
        {
            "id" : 9,
            "name" : "CC-2224 Cody"
        },
    }
}
```

I am quite new to SQL, I already searched a bit around, but I do not even know how this kind of "nested list" is called.

My backup solution would be to create a tuple like this : `"eaten_by" : (0, 3, 9)` which would contain the IDs of the dudes so I can find them later with another call ; but tuples do not seems to exist in SQL.
I also thought about this : `"eaten_by" : "0, 3, 9"`, but my intuition tells me this is a really gross way to do it.

Could someone help me out ? (or only tell me the name of this so I can find it ?)

EDIT : Each `dude` will only get 1 slice of cake maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We HIGHLY avoid nesting lists in a table column. Instead we rely on normalizing our data. In this case you will want a third table to hold the relationship between `cakes` and `dudes`:

Table *cake_eaters*

```
 cake_id | dude_id
  0      |  3
  0      |  9
  0      |  0
```

And now we join to get your result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM cakes
    INNER JOIN cake_eaters ON cakes.id = cake_eaters.cake_id
    INNER JOIN dudes ON cake_eaters.dude_id = dudes.id
```

(as an example)

If, instead, you decide to cram json or a comma delimited list or something else into your `eaten_by` column you will run into the issue that you can't JOIN to `dudes` on that list/json/array. You will have to first parse the list into a sort of ephemeral table (like `cake_eaters`) and do your join on that, which would be really expensive I/O and memory. Plus you can't maintain any index on that so it will also be slow at scale.

If you anticipate doing a lot of work where you have to decide on database schema/design for an application, I would recommend reading up on "Database Normalization". There are plenty of write-ups online on the subject and it will help you think through good RDBMS design practices as well as designs you should avoid.

Comment: Thanks for your help !  
I am thinking about this third table. Each time someone will eat a slice, I will need to insert a new entry, right ?  
And if I want to get a list of cakes and their eaters, would I need to make 2 calls (1 to cakes, and 1 to cake_eaters) or a simple call on cake_eaters will be enough ?

Comment: That is correct. You will need to add a new entry into this relationship table every time a dude eats a cake they haven't eaten before. If you think of a table as an "object" with "attributes" then you can imagine that a relationship is, in fact, an object. And it even has attributes. You may consider adding a column called `date_eaten`, for instance. Every "object" generally gets its own table to store its specific attributes. As for your second question, you would make a single call and `JOIN` the tables together. My `SELECT *` above answers your exact question in this hypothetical schema.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill !
I have edited my question. I tried your solution. It is a great progress, however it does not give me the exact result I want. Do you know if it is a parsing issue or a sql call issue ?